# How do I prevent the mirror-effect in video recordings in Photo Booth?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, photo-booth

I am trying to record a lecture using Photo Booth on my Macbook but I want to be able to record what the professor has on the board. Unfortunately, photobooth seems to have a mirror image, so that all the writing is reversed. How do I get the camera to be a normal non-mirror camera?

Answer (score 21):

Record using QuickTime.

[image: File > New Movie Recording]

I was having same problem and rather than change PhotoBooth to flip all images, I use one app to record people making fun faces and another for lectures.

Comment: Thanks! Note you don't have to record in QuickTime, just choose 'New Movie Recording' from the File menu and it will preview the camera without recording.

Answer (score 19):

In the menu bar click Edit, then "Auto Flip New Items". After you do that, the photos and videos you take will capture what the camera sees, and not reverse it.

[image]

Comment: Does this affect the on-screen live preview? It didn't for me... it's still reversed.

Comment: @LarsH Weirdly, auto-flipping videos doesn't seem to work for me in Yosemite. It still works for photos - the preview is mirrored, but the resulting image is flipped back.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only for photos.

Comment: Answer by Billy Sticker is great workaround (not using Photo Booth).

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

I had exactly this problem for a presentation, so wrote a app called QCamera which supports both mirrored and normal capture.  You can download it for free from the Mac App Store.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id598853070?mt=12

Comment: Thank you for this. I had a presentation to give tonight in which I was showing a live (not recorded) webcam feed on a big external monitor. I couldn't do it in PhotoBooth without it being reversed. I downloaded QCamera and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You should have said, "I wrote this app just to answer this question"

Comment: Thank you!  I spent an hour trying to get VLC to do this without lagging and stuttering - this worked right away.

Comment: Alas, it doesn't seem to work well with other applications.  E.g. It won't fix the problem in Skype.