# Recording video on mac without mirror inversion

Tags: macos, video

What's the best way to record a video on Mac without the camera flipping right and left?

QuickTime doesn't seem to have this option. I tried [QCamera](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id598853070?mt=12) as it was posted as the answer to a similar question [How do I prevent the mirror-effect in video recordings in Photo Booth?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47425/how-do-i-prevent-the-mirror-effect-in-video-recordings-in-photo-booth)
but it doesn't have an option for recording video, only displaying video.

The only way I have access to the camera where the video is not flipped is FaceTime, but I have no way to record it (unless I did a screen capture on top of FaceTime, which just seems unnecessary).

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will flip a video horizontally in QuickTime **after** you stop recording.

In summary:

1. Record a video in QuickTime as usual (it will still show as inverted during this time)
2. Stop recording
3. Shift+Command+H to flip it horizontally
4. Quit the app - it will prompt you to save the file, which will save it in the desired inversion. Alternatively you can File > Export to a variety of formats.

I tested this on macOS Catalina using QuickTime 10.5.

Answer (score -2):

[Quicktime should do the trick, with Shift+Command+H to flip it horizontally.](http://osxdaily.com/2016/02/01/rotate-video-mac-os-x/)

Comment: It doesn't save - the error message is "the video cannot be autosaved because it can't be used in compositions". The Save button is greyed out, and when you try to export it directly, QuickTime just hangs with the Mac circle thing spinning forever.

Comment: @franklinsing okay, but this is a separate issue from the one you asked. Please mark my response as correct if it did indeed answer your question. When I run a test case with a 30 second video, I have both the option of exporting it (with various resolutions), but also sharing it via email,messages, etc. I should note that I am running the current version of MacOS (10.12.5), are you?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you click one of those buttons for exporting it or sharing it via email, messages etc, it just causes QuickTime to hang.

Comment: @franklinsing Would you accept my answer? It answered your question about how to flip the video. I'm not sure why it makes QuickTime hang, you might want to look at `Activity Monitor` to see if there are other processes that are slowing down your computer.